\addfontfeature ignored in polyglossia macros?
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[varwidth,border=0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{spanish}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
\addfontfeature{Color=0000FFFF}
All Fires the Fire and Other Stories.

\textspanish{Todos los fuegos el fuego.}
\end{document}

My expectation is that both lines of text would be blue. This is what I'm seeing, however:

It appears that the \textspanish from polyglossia somehow ignores \addfontfeature -- at least, it appears to ignore the Color option.
My question is: Is this a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly?

polyglossia sets up distinct fonts for different languages.
We can see what is happening by examining the log file created by compiling your example:
Module polyglossia Info: Language spanish was not yet loaded; created with id 2
on input line 18
)
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /home/cfrees/.texlive2024/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.

Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'TeXGyrePagella(0)' created for font 'TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Pagella' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Harfbuzz,Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smcp;
"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/B:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/B:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smc
p;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smc
p;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/BI:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/BI:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+sm
cp;"

So this is the default font for the document, as configured in the preamble.
A bit later, we have
Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'TeXGyrePagella(1)' created for font 'TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Pagella' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Harfbuzz,Ligatures=TeX,Color=0000FFFF].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;color=
{0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smcp;
color={0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/B:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;colo
r={0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/B:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smc
p;color={0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;colo
r={0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smc
p;color={0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/BI:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;col
or={0000FFFF};"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Pagella/BI:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+sm
cp;color={0000FFFF};"

This is a new font defined when you 'add' the colour to the current font after \begin{document}. As far as TeX is concerned, this isn't an addition to the current font; it is a new font. That it is just like the previous one (excepting the colour) is irrelevant.
But when you switch to Spanish, polyglossia ensures that the correct font for that language is used. That font was setup in the preamble, previous to your addition of colour in the body of the document. Consequently, it lacks colour.
fontspec keeps track of fonts, so if you use
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{spanish}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
\addfontfeature{Color=0000FFFF}
All Fires the Fire and Other Stories.

\textspanish{%
  \addfontfeature{Color=0000FFFF}%
  Todos los fuegos el fuego.%
}
\end{document}

everything will be blue and you will still only have configured two font families, just as if you'd only switched English to blue.
Alternatively, if you want everything in blue, you can specify the colour when configuring the main font,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{spanish}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Color=0000FFFF]

\begin{document}
All Fires the Fire and Other Stories.

\textspanish{%
  Todos los fuegos el fuego.%
}
\end{document}

which has the same effect, but avoids creating a font family you don't intend to use.

Thank you for your detailed explanation.

\addfontfeature is somewhat problematic in some cases, and in fact a few settings are not allowed. This is the case with the language system set by polyglossia and babel. For reference, for those who prefer babel (which fully supports luatex and xetex), here is an option based on the declaration of a family, which may be enough in cases like this.
\documentclass[varwidth,border=0.2in]{standalone}

\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{bluerm}[Color=0000FFFF]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\bluermfamily

All Fires the Fire and Other Stories. \foreignlanguage{spanish}{Todos
los fuegos el fuego.}

\rmfamily

All Fires the Fire and Other Stories. \foreignlanguage{spanish}{Todos
los fuegos el fuego.}

\end{document}



Thank you for your suggestion. Although I am sticking with polyglossia, I'm glad you added information for those who use babel.
